# HTML Canvas clip and putImageData

Tags: html, canvas, clip

I have a canvas with a large image in the background and a smaller round image in front of it. I achieved this round image effect by using clip like so

```
ctx.save();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2, true);   
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();

ctx.drawImage(img,x-r,y-r,2*r,2*r);     // draw the image
ctx.restore();
```

then I want to rotate the round image, so I use a second context and rotate and redraw like so

```
backCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');    
backContext=backCanvas.getContext('2d');
backCanvas.width=w;
backCanvas.height=h;

backContext.translate(w/2,h/2);
backContext.rotate(a);

backContext.drawImage(img,-w/2,-h/2,w,h);

var imgData=backContext.getImageData(0,0,w,h);

ctx.save();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2, true);   
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
ctx.putImageData(imgData,x,y);

ctx.restore();
```

But what happens is that the black-transparent background gets copied from the back canvas and the clip fails to "clip" it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just FYI, If the image you are drawing to the canvas is on a different domain, you won't be allowed to call getImageData.

Comment: yes you're absolutely right. I ran into this problem a while back and got around it by issuing the command <--allow-file-access-from-files>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-putimagedata),

> The current path, transformation matrix, shadow attributes, global alpha, **the clipping region**, and global composition operator **must not** affect the getImageData() and putImageData() methods.

In your case, why are you using an additional canvas and pixel data manipulations? Why not just

```
ctx.save();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);   
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();

ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.drawImage(img, -r, -r, 2*r, 2*r);
// not restoring context here, saving the clipping region and translation matrix

// ... here goes the second part, wherever it is:
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(a);
ctx.drawImage(img, -r, -r, 2*r, 2*r);
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: sorry, I'm still new to the concept of clips and transformations. I'll give it a try

Comment: It worked! Thanks. But I had to add a ctx.restore() at the end to make it work