# Mask for putImageData with HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I want to take an irregularly shaped section from an existing image and render it as a new image in Javascript using HTML5 canvases. So, only the data inside the polygon boundary will be copied. The approach I came up with involved:

1. Draw the polygon in a new canvas.
2. Create a mask using `clip`
3. Copy the data from the original canvas using `getImageData` (a rectangle)
4. Apply the data to the new canvas using `putImageData`

It didn't work, the entire rectangle (e.g. the stuff from the source outside the boundary) is still appearing. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269320/html-canvas-clip-and-putimagedata) explains why: 
"The spec says that `putImageData` will not be affected by clipping regions." Dang!

I also tried drawing the shape, setting `context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in"`, and then using `putImageData`. Same result: no mask applied. I suspect for a similar reason.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this goal? Here's basic code for my work in progress, in case it's not clear what I'm trying to do. (Don't try too hard to debug this, it's cleaned up/extracted from code that uses a lot of functions that aren't here, just trying to show the logic).

```
 // coords is the polygon data for the area I want
   context = $('canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
   context.save();
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
   for (i = 2; i < coords.length; i += 2) {
     context.lineTo(coords[i], coords[i + 1]);
   }
   //context.closePath();
   context.clip();

   $img = $('#main_image');
   copy_canvas = new_canvas($img); // just creates a new canvas matching dimensions of image
   copy_ctx = copy.getContext("2d");

   tempImage = new Image();
   tempImage.src = $img.attr("src");
   copy_ctx.drawImage(tempImage,0,0,tempImage.width,tempImage.height);

  // returns array x,y,x,y with t/l and b/r corners for a polygon
  corners = get_corners(coords)
  var data = copy_ctx.getImageData(corners[0],corners[1],corners[2],corners[3]);
  //context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  context.putImageData(data,0,0);
  context.restore();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

dont use `putImageData`,

just make an extra *in memory canvas* with document.createElement to create the mask and apply that with a `drawImage()` and the `globalCompositeOperation` function (depending on the order you need to pick the right mode;

I do [something similar here](http://1.618033988.com/9/) the [code is here](http://1.618033988.com/9/js/image.js) (mind the `CasparKleijne.Canvas.GFX.Composite` function)

Comment: Oh quick question - can you think of a way to do this without three temp. canvases? I've got 1 to load a copy of the main image, then one to copy the rectangle into, and the third which has the mask, to which I apply the 2nd. I feel as if I must be doing too much somewhere, but I can't think of a way to go directly from the full image, to a canvas containing just the rectangle.

Comment: In the code I included you can build a Composite that can jold a list of as many canvases as you want, however, I advise you to do that with care in perspective of performance. So testing and trying is a good practice ;)

Comment: This answer could do with a snippet of the code being added here on SO, or at least a jsfiddle or similar -- mainly because the links are currently broken.