# Transparency lost with getImageData - HTML5 2d Context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

I noticed a strange problem with `getImageData`; transparency of the image seems to be ignored when the image data is fetched.

Since any image needs to be drawn on to a `canvas` before its image data can be obtained, I assumed this was a problem with the `canvas` in question being opaque. But I was wrong, since using the `canvas` as an argument in `drawImage` maintains transparency.

Here is how I loaded the image;

```
var load_image = function(name, url, holder, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        var canvas = make_canvas(e.target.width, e.target.height);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);

        holder[name] = {canvas: canvas, ctx: ctx};

        delete e.target;

        callback.call();
    }, false);
};
```

The `callback` is simply the draw function, which invokes `draw_image` to draw the image.

The usual version;

```
var draw_image = function(ctx, img, sx, sy, w, h, dx, dy) {
    ctx.drawImage(img.canvas, sx, sy, w, h, dx, dy, w, h);
};
```

It simply takes the canvas as an argument for `drawImage`, and the result is as intended with transparency maintained. **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MnG7a/3/)**.

The image data version;

```
var draw_image = function(ctx, img, sx, sy, w, h, dx, dy) {
    var imagedata = img.ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, w, h);
    ctx.putImageData(imagedata, dx, dy);
};
```

This one obtains the image data of the required rectangle from the same canvas as the one used in the usual version, and puts the image data on the canvas I want to draw to. I believe transparency should be maintained, but this is not so. **[Example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80133449/imagedataTest/index.html)**. (This is a Dropbox link because of the `origin-clean` flag.)

Am I wrong in assuming that transparency should be maintained with `getImageData`? Or am I just using it in a wrong manner?

Either way, help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your problem is that putImageData doesn't use a [composite operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing) to blend the source and destination image data.  Rather, it's doing a direct write of the red, green, blue, *and alpha* channels into the canvas.  For fully transparent pixels, this means they may or may not appear in the color you expect.

Instead, you can create an intermediate canvas element, draw to that, and then use drawImage() to render that to your target canvas with the appropriate globalCompositeOperation being applied.  [Mask for putImageData with HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942141/mask-for-putimagedata-with-html5-canvas) discusses this issue in more detail.

Update: You can verify that the data you're writing into your "broken" example actually does have transparent data in it by doing `ctx.getImageData(230,50,1,1).data`. The result is [0,0,0,0] - i.e. a fully transparent pixel.

Comment: I see, that explains it! Thanks for your answer! Though, this really throws a wrench in the works. I was planning on testing if benefits of using `canvas` as 'images' in games(color masking, and perspective transformation without context) outweigh the overhead or not. If I need to introduce an intermediate canvas to draw the transformed image, I might as well stick to using `Image` objects and a rough `canvas` for processing. Thanks, again!