# How to remove background of image using html5 canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas, background, transparent

I want to make online photo cutout app that can remove background of any image and save them back as transparent png image. I have seen photo collage application [remove background](http://editphotosforfree.com) as follows.

[image]

It can be easily done using photoshop which has very advanced techniques but I want very simple way that is implemented in the above mentioned app which use html5 canvas. Just paint over the part of image and get the required part of photo making transparent all the non-painted part.

Comment: Sounds like an great idea. Go ahead, write some code and come back when you've got specific answers. PS: Cute dog :3

Comment: If you search on stack overflow for the same thing, many members have asked the same question, you are sure to find your answer. here are some starting points for you (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271419/how-to-fill-the-opposite-shape-on-canvas     (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269320/html-canvas-clip-and-putimagedata

Comment: I have figured out this - 1. Create 3 canvas layers 2. On bottom layer, draw original image 3. On middle layer, draw the green mask (by painting) and 4. On top layer, get the pixels of bottom layer that is common with the middle layer and draw it on top layer.